# How to Map a Array which contains JSON object in React JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, associative-array

I am getting a JSON object from firebase store in my redux action.
I am storing the JSON objects inside an associative array.
when I am trying to do this.props.expenses, I get back the array.

But I am not able to map the array in JSX??

```
import { SHOW_EXPENSE } from './types';
import database from '../config/firebase';
export const showExpenses = () =>  dispatch => {

const expenses = [];

        database.ref()
        .once('value')
        .then((snapshot) => {


                snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {

                        expenses.push({

                              id: childSnapshot.key,
                              ...childSnapshot.val()        

                        })


                });

        });

        console.log(expenses);

    dispatch({

        type: SHOW_EXPENSE,
        expenses :  expenses     

})

return expenses;

};
```

This is my console.log(expenses);

```
0: {id: "-LUumVQzeXBN8iK81EVO", expense_amount: "500", expense_name: 
"bike service"}
1: {id: "-LUumeeCeYIdd2G4Pz5K", expense_amount: "1500", 
 expense_name: "tire change"}
 length: 2__proto__: 
 Array(0)
```

When I try to map this.props.expenses it returns nothing.

```
{this.props.expenses.map( data =>

      {data.expense_amount}
      {data.expense_name}
});
```

Comment: have you tried to wrap your map data inside div like so:
{this.props.expenses.map( data =>
<div>
      {data.expense_amount}
      {data.expense_name}
</div>
});
}

Comment: @PiyushZalani its still the same , doesnt return anything just empty

Comment: @codemt Where are you using `{this.props.expenses.....` and please make sure that you are getting expenses in props.

Comment: This is an async issue - you return expenses before they've been retrieved from the database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @ic3b3rg no i have tried using if statements to see if it is getting rendered or not.  i get the console logs , but still it is not getting rendered.

Comment: @NirajKaushal i am using this.props.expenses in my component , where i want to map the data i get from the firebase database.

Comment: @codemt check that `this.props.expenses` is being set or not.

Comment: that's just how the console works - expenses is an empty array when you initially log it - by the time you've opened the array in the console, the array has been populated by the response - try `console.log(JSON.stringify(expenses))` - it will be an empty array.

Comment: btw, the fix is to move your `dispatch` inside the `then` block

Comment: @ic3b3rg You are awesome bro .  yes i am getting the data now :) , can you explain why this happened? i am confused a little.

Comment: your database call is asynchronous - that means it will make a request and then carry on with other work, i.e. the code after the database call. When the database request completes, the code in your `then` block is executed - make sense?

Comment: getting it now . thanks a lot man :)